# Finding Borel measures on a closed convex hull

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $M=C(I)^{\ast}$, the space of complex Borel measures on the unit interval $I$. Suppose we give $M$ the weak*-topology induced by the Banach space $C(I)$. Now $\forall$ $t \in I$, let $e_t \in M$ be defined as $e_tf= f(t)$. Also, define $\Lambda \in M$ by $\Lambda f= \int_0^{1} f(t) dt$. Finally, let $K= \{e_t: t\in I\}$, which turns out to be closed (in fact, compact in the weak*-topology through eventually applying Banach-Alaoglu Theorem). Is there a method in finding $\mu$ in the closed convex hull of $K$? I believe $\mu$ is a complex Borel measure, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: What is $\mu$? Did you mean to say weak-$^*$ closed convex hull?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: What is $\mu$? The Lebesgue measure?

Comment: I believe so, though it should be a complex Borel measure.